# jQuery delegated mouseenter event only fires on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to wire up the jQuery mouseenter event to a bunch of links in a container. I also want to cancel navigation of the link so I'm wiring up the click event. All of the sudden the mouseenter handler is only executing after clicking the link. It is still the mouse enter event because if I leave the mouse over the link, and click again it doesn't fire, it only happens once per entry. But only if  I click. Nothing happens when I move the mouse over it. I created a [jsdfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxfqzqk8/1/) to try to show the problem, but I can't reproduce it there. It works as expected. Here's my code:

```
<div>
    <a name="lnkClassTime" href="#">@classTime.ClassTimeHour</a>
</div>
```

Wireup:

```
this.attachSchedule = function () {
    _$classSchedules = $("#classSchedules");

    //..wire up other events

    _$classSchedules.on("mouseenter", "a[name='lnkClassTime']", classTimeMouseEnter);
    _$classSchedules.on("click", "a[name='lnkClassTime']", classTimeClicked);
}

function classTimeClicked() {
    //Fires when I click the link
}

function classTimeMouseEnter() {
    //Only fires if I click the link
}
```

It must be something stupid. Can anyone figure out what is happening?

Comment: Resolved, see my answer below.

Comment: I'd recommend giving an id to the link so that you can avoid the Sizzle selector a[name='lnkClassTime']

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The link is created within an asp.net mvc loop so I would end up with duplicate IDs. Any way around this?

Comment: Then if there are multiple links, use a class name and .eq() to reference the link so that you'd have _$classSchedules.find('.SomeClassName').eq(x).on({'mouseenter':classTimeMouseEnter, 'click':classTimeClicked}); where x is the index of that particular link. Try it out in jsPerf; won't make a difference on desktop but might on tablets and mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried turning it off and back on again? Now I have. It seems to have been Chrome or Chrome developer tools misbehaving. I had had that browser window and tab open to the page for a long time and was reusing it as I developed the page. Despite having refreshed and hard refreshed the page, it was continuing to malfunction. I guess something got out of whack because after I closed Chrome and reopened it, it's behaving correctly.

Edit:
It seems to be reproducible by setting a break point in the mouseenter handler, hitting the breakpoint, and then pressing F5 to refresh the page while execution is paused.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the click event in `classTimeMouseEnter()` function, that should ensure the order of event handling.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't solve it. I don't think the order matters, does it? I can remove the click event/handler altogether and I still have to click for classTimeMouseEnter to run.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be working as expected if I understand correctly.

```js
var clickCount = 0;
var enterCount = 0;

var $container = $("#container");

$container.on("mouseenter", "a[name='lnkClassTime']", classTimeMouseEnter);
$container.on("click", "a[name='lnkClassTime']", classTimeClicked);

function classTimeClicked(){
    $("#clicked").text(++clickCount);
}

function classTimeMouseEnter(){
    $("#entered").text(++enterCount);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <div><a href="#" name="lnkClassTime">8:00 am</a></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div><a href="#" name="lnkClassTime">10:00 am</a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="output">
    <div id="clicked"></div>
    <div id="entered"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right...I said, "I created a jsdfiddle to try to show the problem, but I can't reproduce it there. It works as expected." But on my actual page it works as I described.

Comment: would need to see your actual page then . . .